# Не работает событие onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Вот простой примет]

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку меня куда-то перекидывает(появляется белый экран), как это исправить

Comment: Переименуйте функцию

Comment: Поместите код в вопрос не в виде картинки, а текстом.

Answer (score 2):

Из всех названий функции вы выбрали write переименуйте вашу функцию и будет хорошо

```js
function anyOtherFunction(){
  alert(6)
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="anyOtherFunction()">НАЖАТЬ</button>
```

Потому что есть функция [write](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)()
которая вызовется у вас в таком случае

```html
<button id="button" onclick="write('Ну что нажали? А где кнопка?')">НАЖАТЬ</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло. А почему write нельзя? Это зарезервированное слово?

Comment: Потому что есть функция https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

Comment: Которую вы по cути вызовите находясь в Dom

Comment: Если помогло то галочка снизу под стрелками